# AutoClean doesnt run

Tags: python, pandas

first thank you for your answers it helped me to solve my problem, but now that i run my current script which is here:

```
    from AutoClean.autoclean import AutoClean
    import pandas as pd

    def __init__(self, pipeline, resultat ):
         self.pipeline = pipeline
         self.resultat = resultat
         resultat = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\radia\Downloads\result-(11)-csv.csv", profileUrl = 'str', fullName = 'str', firstName = 'str', lastName = 'str', profileImage = 'str' , additionnalInfo = 'str' , connectionDegree = 'str', job = 'str', location = 'str', sharedConnections = 'str', commonConnection1 = 'str', url = 'str', name = 'str' , query = 'str', category = 'str', timestamp = 'NoneType', commonConnection = 'str', error = 'NoneType') 
    pipeline = AutoClean(resultat, mode = 'manual', duplicates = 'True', missing_num = 'linreg', missing_categ = 'auto', encode_categ = 'False', extract_datetime = 'auto', outliers = 'delete', outlier_param = '1.5', logfile = 'True', verbose = 'True')
    for pipeline in self.pipeline:
        print(pipeline.head())
```

I get this in the terminal:

```
PS C:\Users\radia\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\AutoClean>  c:; cd 'c:\Users\radia\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\AutoClean'; & 'C:\Users\radia\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python3.9.exe' 'c:\Users\radia\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2022.14.0\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher' '52349' '--' 'c:\Users\radia\OneDrive\Bureau\Scripts\automatisation_data_cleaning.py'
```

And just this in output:

```
[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.41 seconds
```

Nothing really changed in the csv document that i'm trying to clean, i'm reading the AutoClean doc and there is adjustable parameters, but i just want first to print the head of my dataframe and it doesnt work..How can i solve this problem ?

Thanks again for reading me,

Answer (score 0):

please refer to [Exception raised: cannot import name 'manual_seed' from 'torch'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73774968/12253480) as this answers the same issue as here.

Hope this helps!