# Exception raised: cannot import name 'manual_seed' from 'torch'

Tags: python, github, repository

i'm trying to run the AutoClean project on my device (here's my code):

```
import random
from AutoClean import AutoClean
import pandas as pd


def __init__(self, pipeline, resultat ):
    self.pipeline = pipeline
    self.resultat = resultat
    resultat = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\radia\Downloads\result-(11)-csv.csv", profileUrl = 'str', fullName = 'str', firstName = 'str', lastName = 'str', profileImage = 'str' , additionnalInfo = 'str' , connectionDegree = 'str', job = 'str', location = 'str', sharedConnections = 'str', commonConnection1 = 'str', url = 'str', name = 'str' , query = 'str', category = 'str', timestamp = 'NoneType', commonConnection = 'str', error = 'NoneType') 
    pipeline = AutoClean(resultat, mode = 'manual', duplicates = 'True', missing_num = 'linreg', missing_categ = 'auto', encode_categ = 'False', extract_datetime = 'auto', outliers = 'delete', outlier_param = '1.5', logfile = 'True', verbose = 'True')
    for pipeline in self.pipeline:
        print(pipeline.head())
```

But i get this exception and can't understand why, especially because i'm testing this since 3 days ago and never got it, so i really dont understand

```
Une exception s'est produite : ImportError
cannot import name 'manual_seed' from 'torch' (unknown location)
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the resulting data frame from AutoClean, you have to call the *output* parameter from the pipeline object:

`df = pipeline.output`

If you would want only the head() of the dataframe, you could do the following:

`pipeline.output.head()`

You can refer to the documentation in the official repo for more details: https://github.com/elisemercury/AutoClean.

Hope this helps!